# Typescript - Cast not working when Record is described as type

Tags: typescript

Hy! Im working with typescript a few weeks now and i got a strange behaviour and i do not really understand the problem.

I created a demo which you can see the error. You have to comment in/out the solutions.
The Problem seems that when i define a Record<K,T> to a type and use this type, it doesnt work, but you can see it in the demo too.

Am i missing some basic understanding of typescript? I have no clue...
Thanks for every help i can get!!!

EDIT:
**I removed id: string from Base and now its working??**

[DEMO](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUHkCUGkEkByBxUBlSAZAqgFXpIgFBEigAuAngA4Cm6AxgPYBO9AvKAN6lij8VaAQwC2ARgBcoAHYBXEQCNaLANy8B-csJEAmKXMXK1ZAL4kyVOqFi1KAZ1CcARAHMmQgDZ2noAD6gnADMmWS8nNXVLegAhITsObnUNAEsAEyk7chZk6RcAGiSBO2Y2OyloWhLUgB5M7Ny8xlZaAD5jMDN1Mig4JFQAdwALWmlQYuay0Aqq6pt7RrQS1tBkh1l41MiaejQ6BmTA5IZHRLINcdLyytYaubsFpbb1TrJmaUzQBTjaKVj4k54ZwEaSkQTsqUCqQA1t4CkD%20BdaJNAXwNAJXO4wlIUWjcZptJJQGI4ai8QItKI9KAdIVcSYSWSAsFQt5sbTGRTxFJieyyZyqTT4WizEKRR1zGA3h87HsDkcpLtKnLjpwvv84uhZYcGBESBLQIhILgIDAECh0Fg8ARiEQok02ACiBpOYSDEpVE7ydoqW6jEROna7icMZ5vH4mSEwhE7X8EjwUukxlkcvlPQilpNpjdasmGvbWmoXmBDcb%20qwoSnQEMRmMMwqMys1htbdt8w5OFmWLdbPd8087Yr9trHec623CyQpeRPt9ft8R8DE2CIdDYWnaxM2WSQ1jEoyvaJCTz9-jKVIaWT6euNEFI6y9yeXdyCifBGfqdeBGYNGZOlOxlq8qakqw6qvOGqDsqup6vqPRmqgACCyAIUgEDwLgAASkB4CsiZ1CmAD8RH6gOSyOkKT4yPI7rtGi-L6NRfqmCRrZBs4bihj4-i3iy4QsVYsbkaSG6XFM1xdjm9T5H2tFFqAZAllW5aVtWoyIpMiwTI2oDrLQmwWK2mmlCcnbdvMMlbFYkGgacwnqfWEyyfq-5qj8oCCZwOKjputmMju95eY%20BLPryeL0R%20Qo-gy27MrugX7pRPKRWF3rnqF-BisKzzOUw7zTjKIFAdZRwnK5oAQYBOpAA)

```js
type Score = {
    team1: number;
    team2: number;
}

type Keys = "goals" | "fouls";

type Base = {
    id: string,
    scores: Record<string, Score>;
}

// NOT working when scores: Scores is used
type Scores = Record<Keys, Score>;

// Does not work in TS 4.2.3 but works in TS 4.1.5
type Specific = {
    scores: Scores; // with inline Record<Keys, Score> it works
}

const base: Base = {
    id: "fsdfdks",
    scores: {
        "goals": {
            team1: 1,
            team2: 2
        },
        "fouls": {
            team1: 1,
            team2: 2
        }
    }
}

const specific: Specific = base as Specific; // error
```

Comment: It is strange. It works with [TS 4.1.5](https://tsplay.dev/mxaB1W) but dont works with [TS 4.2.3](https://tsplay.dev/wQY5Gw). It is strange that type aliasing might affect it

Comment: ohh ok, i didnt check the versions but you are right! I will check some changelogs

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42149) and [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42284), I left a comment in first PR. I think [smarter-type-alias-preservation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#smarter-type-alias-preservation) caused it

Comment: I'm guessing it's the difference between a variance-based comparison (which is quick but sometimes gets things wrong) and a full structural comparison (which is most accurate but sometimes takes a long time), and having an intervening alias triggers one and not the other... but I don't know enough about the compiler specifics to know for sure.

Comment: Probably it has to do with Typescript struggling to solve the differences between the types Base and Specific, not guessing that Keys is a subset of string for the Record. If your logic allows for it, I would declared both Records (in Base and Specific) as either using Keys or string, and then declare Specific as `type Specific = Omit<Base, 'id'>`

Comment: @jcalz do you think it should be filled as a bug ?

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine pls check my edit, its working now when i delete the id prop from Base?!

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine ‍♂️

Comment: If it works- go for it. Also you can create a bug in typescript repo and get an official explanation